# What is the Star of David theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

I came across a MathWorld entry for the [Star of David Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarofDavidTheorem.html), but it doesn't provide much context.

I have never heard of this before, can somebody explain its significance and any applications it might be associated with?

Comment: It seems that is about the relative position of coefficients in the triangle of Tartaglia. The geometrical hexagonal structure of the star fits in the triangle.